# I cannot tell if this is an associative entity or a relationship?

Tags: database, erd, database-management

The question is as follows..

*"A car company has a database where each car has an identifying serial number and a manufacturing completion date. Each car is an example of a certain model. All models have an identification number, name(e.g., Camry), and designer. Over time, the company often manufactures thousands of cars of a certain model, and the model design is specified before any single car exists. b.The car manufacturer (see above) employs technicians who are responsible for inspecting the cars before they are shipped to customers. Each car must be inspected by at least two technicians (identified by their employee number). For each separate inspection, the company needs to record its date and a quality evaluation grade."*

So, I'm thinking that there is a relationship attribute between TECHNICIAN and CAR. I'm making the assumption that the TECHNICIAN inspects 0 to many cars. The relationship attribute contains date completed and quality inspection grade.

Do you think this is right?

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. An assocaitive entity can be made for any ER relationship. There is no term "relationship attribute". By "relationship" do you mean FK? Are you trying to talk about having an entity as attribute of another entity & the first entity's id being a FK in the other's table? But in true ER entities are not attributes of other entities, entities appear together in relationships. Please explain what you mean. Tell us the information modeling & database design reference you are following & refer to is. Use its terms, as it does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship between Technician and Car, because each car is inspected by *at least* two Technicians.

So that is a many to many between Technician and Car, and would require an additional join table, called Inspection, which has a foreign key into both Car and Technician.